# PHPMyAdmin Query error in php #1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
//GET FACEBOOK LIKE DATA TO FACEBOOK SERVERS
function readFacebookLikes($url) {
$query = "select like_count from link_stat WHERE url ='" . $url ."'";
$s = file_get_contents("https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=".
         urlencode($query)."&format=json");
preg_match("#(\"like_count\"):([0-9]*)#",$s,$ar);
if(isset($ar[2])) return $ar[2]; else return null;
}

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('odrinhasedm')  or die(mysql_error());

$query=mysql_query("select nome, url from participacao")  or die(mysql_error());
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$likes = "http://[ip]/evento-odrinhas-edm-open-air/".$res['url'];
$links = $res['url'];
$contador = readFacebookLikes($likes);

//echo'<tr><td>'.$res['nome'].'</td><td>'.$contador.'</td></tr>';

$query1 = "UPDATE participacao set likes = $contador WHERE url = $links "; 
mysql_query($query1) or die (mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Why is this query1 not working? (PHPMyAdmin errror  #1064)

I have a project that creates a page per user on a form and each page has its own Facebook like system, now I have a way to get that data and show it on a table, but I want to insert that data into my database to sort it. Is it easier to add the values to my db or sort the table directly in php?

I have a query that is working and its pulling the URLs to the PHP file, then I want to create another query to insert the data into the database with "update".

Comment: If you really are trying to run this through phpMyAdmin, that's your problem right there. You've pasted PHP code; phpMyAdmin is an administrative tool for managing MySQL databases and doesn't interpret PHP code. What you should instead do is run this through a PHP interpreter (normally done by accessing it through your webserver). If that's already what you're doing, you're getting a MySQL error 1064, not phpMyAdmin, and your post is misleading us.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem was in this case, so I am voting to close as not containing enough information to diagnose.

Comment: (1) MySQL is not phpMyAdmin. (2) Your $query1 is not quoting the strings; at least echo your query and check what is wrong first.

Answer (score 3):

I think url is a string. So you must have quotes around the values:

```
UPDATE participacao set likes = $contador WHERE url = '$links'
```